# Import vanilla ES6 extended class into React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

How do I import vanilla ES6 classes and extended classes into a ReactJS project **without** using `React.Component`?

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Log} from './lib/Log';
import {CoolLog} from './lib/CoolLog';
import {HotLog} from './lib/HotLog';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        ...
    }
    doLog() {
        var coolLog = new CoolLog();
        coolLog.log('Cool!');
        var hotLog = new HotLog();
        hotLog.log('Hot!');
    }
    render() {
        ...
    }
}

export default App;
```

**lib/Log.js**

```
export class Log {
    _log(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
}
```

**lib/CoolLog.js**

```
import {Log} from './lib/Log';

export class CoolLog extends Log {
    log(data){
      this._log('❄️'+data+'❄️');
    }
}
```

**lib/HotLog.js**

```
import {Log} from './lib/Log';

export class HotLog extends Log {
    log(data){
      this._log(''+data+'');
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue was with the path of imports in the extended classes, see my answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49960245/482916).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sample did not illustrate the structure the class files (stored in a `lib` directory) which was where the problem lied.

`lib/CoolLog.js` and `lib/HotLog.js` should import `./Log.js` and not `lib/Log.js` since it is in the same folder.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to import it you have to export it first:

```
export class Log {
    _log(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done that but it's still not importing it. Updating my question.

Comment: @gmoz22 you also have to import `Log` class to `CoolLog.js` and `HotLog.js` file

Comment: I get: Failed to compile. Module not found: Can't resolve './CoolLog'

Comment: I tried importing Log for CoolLog and HotLog but same issue. Updating my question

Comment: I realized my mistake was with the path... Updating my code to properly illustrate it.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing `Log` but using `_log`. `_log` is not defined anywhere. Use `this._log` instead. When you extend some class, you can use the methods of that parent class using `this`.

Here, it works perfectly.

```
export class CoolLog extends Log {
    log(data){
        this._log('❄️'+data+'❄️');
    }
}
```

[image]

Learn more about extends [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends).